# rxjs switch unwrapping observable

Tags: rxjs

I setup a subject and then put some methods on it. It seems to work as intended until it gets to .switch() which I thought would simply keep track of the last call. I get the error `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'ApiChange'` It seems to convert it to type ApiChange from an observable. I don't understand this behavior. Should I be using a different operator?

---

**Service:**

```
  private apiChange = new Subject<ApiChange>();
  apiChange$ = this.apiChange.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged().debounceTime(1000).switch();
```

---

**Component:**

```
  this.service.apiChange$.subscribe(change => {
            this.service.method(change);
        });
```

Comment: Hey there! Can you please help clarify what you meant with "keep track of the last call" ? switch() expects to be called on a high-order observable chain (observable that emits observables rather than values)

Comment: Just that the most recent selection is what is returned.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean by this: switch() expects to be called on a high-order observable chain (observable that emits observables rather than values)

Comment: The example from the documentation [1] shows a case where observables are emitted and not values. [1] https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/switch.md

Comment: I will attempt an answer based on your clarification of what you meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**.debounceTime(1000)** will already assure you will only get a maximum of one value emitted from your observable chain per second. All the values preceding the 1 second quiet time will already be discarded.

With a simple **Subject** (not a **ReplaySubject**), past values are not provided to subscribers anyway.

You probably just want to skip the **.switch()** and enjoy the chain without it.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This makes perfect sense.

Comment: Hmm ends up not working in the case that a call is fired after the debounce that takes less time than the other call to return.

Comment: Without more context, it would be difficult for me to make a useful comment. Can you please help clarify whether you make http calls as part of your subscribe method and only use it's results in a different subscribe? Then I would recommend using switchMap() as part of the observable chain and make the http call there. This would "cancel" previous http calls and only process the latest response

Comment: Yes I want to have a subscriber that calls a method which makes the http calls. Tried using switchMap like this `apiChange$ = this.apiChange.asObservable().debounceTime(1000).switchMap(
    (data) => {
      return new Observable<ApiChange>(observer => observer.next(data));
    });`

You're exactly right in what I want to do in cancelling previous http calls, I'm just not sure how to do it. The switchMap didn't work I'm guessing because I'm actually creating new observers for each one?

Comment: Please join me on the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136625/rxjs-switch-unwrapping-observable-discussion-between-zack-lucky-and-ben-dadseta to discuss this further.